# How does WhatsApp restore chat database after a factory reset

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Consider the following scenario:

- The chat database (msgstore.db.crypt12) is encrypted with a key.
- The key is lost after performing a factory reset.
- I put the db files back in their place (internal storage -> whatsapp 
  -> databases) and install Whatsapp.
- After verification it prompts to restore messages and on confirmation
  it restores them.

How does it restore the messages without key?

Comment: the key is probably stored on their servers, and when restoring, the app gets the key from their servers.

Comment: you can try copying the file, removing whatsapp, replacing the file and toggle airplane mode. it wont work.